# React render inside class tag instead id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I have a requirement to render same data into multiple places via react.
So instead of rendering that via id (via below code), i want to use class tag.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')); // Working

ReactDOM.render(<App />, $('.app')); // Not working.
```

My html is like below...

```
<div class="app" id="app"><div>
<div class="app"><div>
<div class="app"><div>
```

**Update: below is my jsx file.**

```
class PList extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        results: []
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: this.props.results
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.results.map((item, i) => {
                        return <li>{item.Name}</li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

var PRender = ReactDOM.render(<PList />, $('.app'));

function Professionals(data) {
    PRender.setState({
        results: data.Results
    });
}
```

Comment: use the id and add `<div class="app"><div>
<div class="app"><div>` inside the main `App` like `render() {return (<div class="app"><div>
<div class="app"><div>)}`

Comment: Cannot do like this. rendering blocks/divs have no connection. They are at different places and cannot be placed inside same div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer for your edition.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-payne-1tloe?fontsize=14

[image: Edit hopeful-payne-1tloe]

Same as @Alona's answer. I tried to use `jQuery` -> `$('.app')` which described on question.

```js
function App({index}) {
  return `<div>App - ${index}</div>`;
}

$.each($('.app'), (index, app) => ReactDOM.render(<App index={index + 1} />, app))
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="app" id="app"></div>
  <div class="app"></div>
  <div class="app"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my question and added my jsx file. Can you help me to add your code into my jsx as per the need.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi, plz check on `CodeSandbox` above. It will help you to run your code base. Thanks

Comment: This resolve my edit too. Thanks for the quick update @GeorgeWang

Answer (score 3):

`$('.app')` - this is just an array, and `ReactDOM.render` requires single element as second parameter.
You can try as following if you need to render multiple `App`.

```js
function App({index}) {
  return `<div>App - ${index}</div>`;
}
document.querySelectorAll('.app').forEach((app, index) => ReactDOM.render(<App index={index + 1} />, app));
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="app">No ID assigned to App</div>
  <div class="app"></div>
  <div class="app"></div>
  <div class="app"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my question and added my jsx file. Can you help me to add your code into my jsx as per the need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alona, want to accept your answer as well but cannot do that. But thanks alot again!!!